# How to map a procedural brick texture to a sphere?

Tags: procedural

Is there a way to map a procedural brick texture to a sphere ? I tried with Textures Coordinates and Mapping nodes, but it's still not good.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Enter Edit Mode on the Sphere Object, press <kbd>U</kbd> and unwrap using "Sphere Project".
In the Node Editor, press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>>>Texture>>Texture Coordinate and connect the "UV" Output with the "Vector" Input in the Brick Texture node. Finished!

[image]

I hope this helps you ;)