# How can I put my brick texture on all sides of my object?

Tags: shaders

I created a brick texture. I am relatively new to the shading editor. When I put the material on the object, it is stretching on the side. I read that it might be better to put the Texture Coordinate on UV (not sure if this is only with cube like shapes?), but when I do this no material shows at all.

How can I get the material on all sides on my object?

Here is the file: [image]

[image]

Comment: If you connect the *UV* socket instead of the *Object* socket from the *Texture Coordinate* node to the *Vector* socket of the *Mapping* node, you must remove the 90° X rotation...

Comment: To make it work, you need to use UV coordinates. In order for the UV socket to work, you must first _unwrap_ your mesh so it has a valid UV map.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112843/how-can-i-make-my-procedural-brick-texture-map-correctly-to-both-a-cube-and-cyli https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70444/how-to-create-a-procedural-brick-texture-for-a-simple-building-without-object-si https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90387/how-to-map-a-procedural-brick-texture-to-a-sphere