How do I get the brick texture to apply to all faces on an object?
I'm almost brand new to blender and I'm trying to make a Building with multiple faces, some of the faces are just a flat mirror whereas the others are applying the brick texture. I tried splitting the entire model into faces and texturing them individually but with no luck, I also tried using different object as reference and that didn't work either.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112843/how-can-i-make-my-procedural-brick-texture-map-correctly-to-both-a-cube-and-cyli/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90387/how-to-map-a-procedural-brick-texture-to-a-sphere/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70444/how-to-create-a-procedural-brick-texture-for-a-simple-building-without-object-si/70571#70571
